# What controls a textBox background color when readonly is set to true or false

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, background-color

Usually when we set readonly true or false in a textbox, the background automatically switches into grey or white.

But, on my code, in some specific cases I wanna have to turn the background red, or green, etc. for a moment, and later I want it to behave normaly.

The problem is that after I set the background to red, when I change the readonly setting, the color won't change back into grey or white, I've been using the following code to get it to grey (read only), but I want it to auto change the color as it used before.

```
textBox1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
```

Comment: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: I don't exactly know how to answer it, how can I verify it? I'm using Visual c# 2010 express edition @Saifur

Comment: What project did you create? Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET??  __You__ really should know that! Look at the using clauses at the top of your code..!

Comment: ahh.. i got it, it's a winforms project :)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(textBox1.BackColor.ToString());
  textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
  Console.WriteLine(textBox1.BackColor.ToString());`will show that it is `SystemColors.Window`.

Comment: @TaW That's not the question, what i wanna do is change the backcolor to gray or white automatically again, after setting it to readonly true or false.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna reset the way the BackColor is set, you simply use the following method

textBox1.ResetBackColor();

And it will turn the background to white or grey accordingly to read only again